# mVenus fluorecent protein, life time? luminosity?

Tags: decay

If fluorescence proteins get excited by radiation, how long does it usually take for the excitation to decay (at room temperature)?

I guess, if the life time is too long, the luminosity will be very low. Do you know something about how luminous the fluorescence can be?

Comment: what exactly you wanna know? Life-time of fluorescence is on the order of nano seconds